# Cannot fire subroutine inside a hash of subroutines in perl

Tags: perl, subroutine, dereference, perl-hash

Hi I'm quite new to perl. I have a perl hash containing subroutines. I've tried to run it in various ways that I found online. But nothing seems to work. 
My code :

```
%hashfun = (

start=>sub { print 'hello' },
end=>sub { print 'bye' } 

);
```

And I've tried the following and more.

```
print "\n $hashfun{start} \n";
```

which results in the following output:

> CODE(< HexaDecimal Value >)

Then I tried

```
print "\n $hashfun{start}->() \n";
```

which results in the following

> CODE(< HexaDecimal Value >) ->()

How to fix?

Comment: You can't run a coderef inside a string interpolation.

Comment: Also refer to  *"Quote and Quote-like Operators"* in [`perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) for information of what can be interpolated inside a string.

Comment: Thanks mate I will @HåkonHægland

Comment: @simbabque you can run a coderef inside of a string: `my %h=(a=>sub{'hi';}); print "${\$h{a}->()} there\n";` It's not pretty and I wouldn't necessarily recommend it, but it works

Comment: @stevieb I have an explanation of how to do it with an array ref below in my answer. I did say _you can't_ on purpose. Your example with the scalar ref is shorter but still ugly and shouldn't be done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your last attempt ist the right syntax, but in the wrong place. You cannot run code inside of a string interpolation<sup>1</sup>. Move it outside of the double quotes `""`.

```
print "\n";
$hashfun{start}->();
print"\n";
```

It's important not to `print` the actual call to `$hashfun{start}`, because that would return `1`. That's because a sub in Perl always returns the return value of the last statement inside the sub (which can be a `return`). Here, it's a `print`. And the return value of `print` is `1` if the printing succeeded. So `print "\n", $hashfun{start}->(), "\n";` would output

```
hello
1
```

---

<sup>1) Actually you can, but you really shouldn't.`print "\n@{[&{$hashfun{start}}]}\n";` will work. It's very magical and you should really not do that.</sup>

<sup>Because arrays can be interpolated into strings, an array deref works inside of double quotes. The stuff inside that deref is being run, so the `&$hashfun{start}` (which is a different way of calling the coderef) gets run. But because it returns `1` and that's not an array ref, we need to wrap it in `[]` to put it into an array ref that is then being dereferenced. **Please don't use that!**</sup>

Comment: Yes that is the correct answer. Thank you. When I apply that fix, number 1 is appearing after the printed value. Why is that? and any way to get rid of it. I mean I get the output as 'hello1' and 'bye1'

Comment: @Ihsan I've already explained where the `1` is coming from. I had actually expected it to be directly behind the text, and if you look at [the initial version of the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40762327/1) I've had it like that. But on my Perl 5.20.1 it doesn't do that. I am not sure why. It has to do with the order in which stuff gets evaluated. The `print` gets called, and it has three args. The second arg is the code ref, which gets run. That does the `print 'hello'`. So there is output. Then it returns `1`, which is passed to `print`. The two `"\n"` are also ...

Comment: .. passed to `print`. I'm not clear on whether an argument list is concatenated and printed internally, or if they each get printed separately. That might also be influenced by `$|`, but I really don't know. Maybe someone with deeper knowledge of the internals will explain this later.